# Error running make - array type has incomplete element type

Tags: gcc, make, makefile

I am trying to install libbow library. When i run make file the following error is generated

```
gcc -c   -Ibow -I. -I./argp -DHAVE_LIBNSL=1 -DHAVE_STRERROR=1 -DHAVE_GETTIMEOFDAY=1 -DHAVE_RANDOM=1 -DHAVE_SRANDOM=1 -DHAVE_SETENV=1 -DHAVE_STRCHR=1 -DHAVE_STRRCHR=1 -DHAVE_ALLOCA_H=1  -g -O -Wall -Wimplicit -o array.o array.c
In file included from array.c:22:
./bow/libbow.h:2128: error: array type has incomplete element type
make: *** [array.o] Error 1
```

The Source of libbow is :http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~mccallum/bow/src/
(The latest version)

Search results showed it as a compiler problem. How to resolve this? Or is there any other source for libbow?

Comment: Which version of gcc are you using?

Answer (score 0):

The error points line 2128 of `bow/libbow.h`

```
extern struct argp_child bow_argp_children[];
```

It means that `struct argp_child` is not defined.

I noticed that in line 1346 there is a forward declaration of the structure.

```
struct argp_child;      /* forward declare this type */
```

The full declaration of the structure is in line 245 of `argp/argp.h`

To resolve this issue you can either

- Use include of `argp.h` in `libbow.h`

  i.e `#include "../argp/argp.h"`
- Copy `struct argp_child` definition in `libbow.h` (not recommended)

An other thought is that you might compiling `array.c` from wrong directory and `-Ibow -I. -I./argp` does not point to the correct directories.